# How to create a road graph using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, road, graph

There are many cars with GPS transmitters that drive along quarry roads. These are temporary roads, they change frequently and
not on the maps. GPS data is not very accurate, outliers need to be filtered

[image]

I want to summarize this data and **build a road graph**. Which I will update after a certain time for actualization.
I tried using clustering algorithms (DBScan and KMeans) in Python. I received the following:

[image]

But it's just an unrelated set of data. And I don’t know yet what to do with this next.

Any ideas on how to make a road graph using PostGIS without using Python and clustering algorithms?
I found a good article on how to work with a graph, but this is the next step for me:
https://medium.com/@theduke.lp/graph-and-geospatial-analysis-with-pgrouting-3417d98d7d41

Comment: If you are open to other technologies, you can use QGIS, there is an algorithm called "point to path", it will help you to create the lines, however, you may have to group your points and order them, the algorithm will join them then create lines. You will be able to save your data in PostGIS.

Comment: Are these quarry roads part of OpenStreetMap?

Comment: postgis has ST_MakeLine https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html you can aggregate your points with this after a QA of your source data.

Comment: @GforGIS: I need to automate creation of a road graph. As I know, QGIS is not suitable for this.

Comment: @Timothy Dalton: No

Comment: @Mapperz: Thanks, I'll think about it